# этимология, происхождение слова

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением вопроса. Объясните различия между словами с точки зрения происхождения.
этаж – одноэтажный
аналогия    –   аналогичный
квартира    –   квартирный

Comment: Не могу понять сути вопроса...

Comment: это полный вопрос, он размещен в одном из тестов для поступления в университет, также не понимаю сути вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, имеется в виду не этимология, а словообразование, какое слово от какого образовано. Ясно, что прилагательные одноэтажный, аналогичный и квартирный образованы от существительных - этаж, аналогия и квартира. Не было бы квартиры, не возник бы и квартирный вопрос.